# Waiting for or waiting on

Tags: prepositions

Meaning of **wait on somebody/something** is **to wait for something to happen before you do or decide something**

So I think its usage is correct in the following sentence

> It was barely midnight when I arrived home but I found them both sitting at the table **waiting on me**.

But according to my book it should be **waiting for me**.

Although **waiting for** is also correct but I don't think **waiting on** is wrong.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44452/wait-on-vs-wait-for  - This should answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

`waiting _on_ someone to arrive` is fairly common (spoken) usage, but would be considered vulgar/uneducated usage by most people, `waiting _for_ someone to arrive` would generally be considered more correct.